# how to call 2 different methods of Child from Parent using useImperativeHandler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a parent component where I need to call 2 methods of its Child. I am able to call one using useImperativeHandler like

```
const Parent = () => {
  const childRef = useRef();

  return (
    <div>
      <Child ref={childRef} />
      <Button onClick={() => childRef.current.methodOne()}>
        Submit
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

and then in Child Compoennt

```
const Child = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    () => ({
      methodOne() {
        // some code
      },
    }),
    []
  );

  return;
});
```

So far it works very ok.
But I want another button in the Parent component to call a **second method**(let's call it methodTwo) in the same Child. How can I do it?

Comment: there is a specific reason to use the method useRef ?

Comment: @דולבדובלון do you suggest another way calling a Child component from Parent?

Comment: yes , pass the function to the child and let the child call the function, do you want an example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Found the answer. userImperativeHandle takes multiple methods like this and you can call them normally in Parent Component.

```
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    methodOne: () => {
    },
    methodTwo: () => {
    }
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

check this example , i tried to make it vary simple to understand , but if you get into trouble i am happy to even help you on  a zoom call

this is the basic concept in react , to pass a method from parent to child

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yh2wau?file=src%2FChild.jsx

i am passing a console.log function from parent to child in this example

and the 2 buttons call different methods like what you want to do .

hopes that makes sense!

for more information and learning i suggest going through the documentation of  React

try [this tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html)
it will give you the basics